# SpriteKit properly handling sounds

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, audio

I have a SpriteKit game where I have a number of different Sprites Lasers, Planes, etc.  A number of these Sprites have a sounds that will play whenever they are visible.  Right now I play the sound in the SKSpriteNode itself.  This probably isn't what I want because if I have I have 50 of the same sprites, they'll all be playing the same sound and gobbing resources.  However, I'm not really sure where would be the best place to play the the sound, because for some of these sprites I would need to check if it should be playing or not.  I suppose I could put the sounds in the the GameScene and loop through all sprites during every update to determine what sounds should and should not still be playing, that way there would only be one instance of every sound.  I was hoping to keep all the sprite code within the sprite itself, but this would solve the issue with multiple instances of the same sound playing.  Is this the correct way to handle sounds?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Are you asking if more than one of sprite A is in view then only play sound B once? Please give a specific example.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for an answer to, so if I have 50 of the same sprites on the screen, I don't want to have each sprite playing the same sound.  I only want the sound played once for all 50 of the sprites instead of each sprite trying to play the same sound at the same time.  So as an example if I have 50 planes, I dont want to play 50 propeller sounds, just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to give you a proper code example without seeing your code. You can however get the gist of what you can try with what I have below.

In MyScene add a property `BOOL propSound`.

Whenever you create a new plane and wonder about adding the prop sound do something like this:

```
if(propSound == false)
{
    propSound = true;
    // add your code to play prop sound
}
```

If you add every newly created plane sprite into a NSMutableArray like this `[yourArrayName addObject:newPlane];`, you can check the array count every time you remove a plane in order to know if the last plane was removed and the sound needs to be stopped.

```
if([yourArrayName count] == 0)
{
    propSound = false;
    // add your code to stop prop sound
}
```

Comment: That was what I was looking for, was if I should move the sound code to the Scene rather than the Node itself, the Scene can check if any of the instances of a particular sprite type should be playing a sound and if they are play or continue playing and if not, stop the sound.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like this?

```
NSMutableArray *coin = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
SKAction *_coinSound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"Pickup_Coin4.wav"   waitForCompletion:NO];
    [coin addObject:_coinSound];
    SKAction *_playCoinSound = [SKAction sequence:coin];
```

Then I just check if the "character" in my case touched the coin. If so it will play the sound.

```
if([_adventurer intersectsNode:coin]){
            [coin runAction:_playCoinSound];
}
```

Edit:

Saw your comment on your question. I guess you could check if there is at least 1 plane on the screen, if so then you could play a loop of the sound. If there is less than 1 no sound.

Do not play the same sound again if there already are playing. You could use a BOOL to see if the sound is already playing.

```
BOOL isPlaneSoundOn = false;

if(!isPlaneSoundOn && _planeNode.count > 0){
 //play the sound
 isPlaneSoundOn = true;
} else if(_plane.count == 0) {
 //stop the sound
 isPlaneSoundOn = false;
}
```

Something like that. Maybe you get the idea :)

Comment: Playing a sound isn't the issue, the issue is that if I have multiple sprites that make a constant sound, like a propeller on a plane I don't want every sprite playing and instance of the same sound and gobbing resources, I just want to play that sound once.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally play any community sounds off the scene using the SKAction playSoundWithFilename, and assign this sound a key.

Then I would check if the key exists, and if it does not, then play the sound